# RestApiSDK references outdated PayPalCoreSDK dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, dll, paypal

**Solution below**

I'm trying to implement PayPal payment in an ASP.NET website, but when I run it on Azure, it tells me the assembly being referred to by RestApiSDK 0.1.1.0 is wrong. Local it all works.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b4afc1ccaef40fb' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I checked with .NET Reflector and the assembly being referred to is indeed 1.5.2.0, though the latest version in NuGet Packages is 1.6.0.0. I also uninstalled both packages and re-installed them, but no luck.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why does this work on my localhost?
2. How do I fix this to work on Azure Websites as well?

Edit: As @JasonZ suggested, I installed a new version of the PayPal SDK for .NET and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, but do you only need the PayPal REST functionality with your website?  If so, the [PayPal .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal) has since replaced the RestApiSDK library and removes the dependency on PayPalCoreSDK.

Comment: Hey @JasonZ, I guess I could upgrade to the .NET SDK then. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by @JasonZ: The [PayPal .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal) has since replaced the RestApiSDK library and removes the dependency on PayPalCoreSDK.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be 32 bit local machine vs 64 bit azure?

If that's not the case, I would try manually adding them to the GAC via a webjob as stated here:

http://blogs.infosupport.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-in-windows-azure/

When you "uninstall and Reinstall" do you see them in the GAC on your azure vm?

=Devon

Comment: Hey @DevOpsDevon, unfortunately we don't have access to a VM.

Comment: Is your dev machine 32 bit?

Comment: Hey, thanks for following up. My dev is 64bit and so is the Azure website we're running, but the problem has been solved by @JasonZ's comment above. I'll close this here ticket. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the nuget package

PM> install-package PayPalCoreSDK -version 1.7.0

(To upgrade the package using visual studio [Top Menu] -> Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)

Please follow the following link for more information.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCoreSDK/